# Calculating phosphorescence quantum yield using the given datas'

Tags: physical-chemistry, photochemistry

> A molecular excited state has a fluorescence lifetime of 10 nanoseconds and a phosphorescence life time of 10 microseconds. There are no other processes, what's the phosphorescence quantum yield?

I divided the above two lifetimes naively to get $0.1\%$.  I believe we can use the equation $\phi_f = k_r \times \tau_f$, and similarly for $\phi_p$, then divide the two. But I am not sure at all. Can anyone guide me how should I solve this question and is my answer correct?

Comment: Can you explain the different terms in your equation?  The fluorenscence quantum yield? and the fluorenscence lifetime?  It's not clear what you think is actually going on chemically/physically.

Comment: $\tau_f$ is the fluorescence lifetime, $\phi_f$ is the fluorescence quantum yield....

Answer (score 1):

The triplet can only be formed by intersystem crossing from the singlet. The fluorescence yield is $\phi_f=k_f^0/(k_f^0+k_i)$ where $k_i$ is the intersystem crossing rate constant to form the triplet and $k_f^0$ the radiative rate constant for fluorescence. The fluorescence lifetime is $\tau=1/(k_f^0+k_i)=10\cdot 10^{-9}$. The triplet yield is $1-\phi_f$. The triplet lifetime is not important and as the triplet only phosphoresces (you mention no other processes, so no, non-radiative, pathway from triplet) all the  molecules formed must phosphoresce (and it does not matter how long this takes as its the only pathway out of the triplet.)  However, you still have one piece of evidence missing, namely $k_f^0$.

Comment: Since $\tau=1/(k_f^0+k_i)=10\cdot 10^{-9}$ wouldn't knowing either $k_f^0$ or $k_i$ be sufficient?

Comment: it is not possible to get to triplet state without $k_i>0$, so if *only* fluorescence occurs $k_i=0$ (no intersystem crossing) and so no triplet. If $k_f^0 =0$ no fluorescence and all triplet, so in this case triplet yield is 1 but then no fluorescence can occur but this is not what happens as the fluorescence lifetime is given. The question cannot be answered without more information.